# Why is the Yoneda product sometimes called cup product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, terminology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

In algebraic topology there is the [cup product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_product), which endows the direct sum of (singular) cohomology groups with the structure of an associative, graded-commutative, unital ring. Given an associative, unital ring $R$, there is also the [Yoneda product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_product) between Ext groups of $R$-modules. If $R$ is commutative, then the direct sum of Ext groups $\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,M)$ becomes a graded ring, for any $R$-module $M$.

Sometimes the Yoneda product is called *Yoneda cup product*. Why is that? What is the connection between both notions?

Comment: IIRC the Yoneda product reproduces the cup product in sheaf cohomology, or something like that.

Comment: For example, the Yoneda product on $\text{Ext}^{\bullet}_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ is the cup product on the group cohomology of a group $G$, which is in turn the cup product on the singular cohomology of the classifying space $BG$. This generalizes but I'm not sure what the right category is to state the generalization in.

Comment: [Maybe relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/674/what-is-a-cup-product-in-group-cohomology-and-how-does-it-relate-to-other-branc).